# VB.Net Open image from database to picturebox

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm trying to open an image from my **database** to a **picture box** but I just don't how to do it.
I've searched for some answers and I am not familiar with the codes for I am beginner only.

The only codes that I researched about are for connecting the database to the system:

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public acsconn As New OleDbConnection
    Public acsdr As OleDbDataReader
    Public acsda As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Public acscmd As New OleDbCommand
    Public strsql As String
    Public acsds As New DataSet
    Public Sub connect()
        Try
            acsconn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=|datadirectory|\database1.mdb;"
            acsconn.Open()
            If acsconn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MsgBox("Connected")
            Else
                MsgBox("Error")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception


        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

I do not know what is next. BTW, those codes - I used it for saving the image to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the sort of thing you are looking for:

```
 Private Sub HandleRequest(context as HttpContext)
      Dim SqlCnn As SqlConnection = Nothing, sql As String
      Dim emp_id As Integer
      emp_id = Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString("id"))
      ConnectDB(SqlCnn)
      Try
        sql = "SELECT image FROM employees (NOLOCK) WHERE ID =" & emp_id
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstr, SqlCnn)
        Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData)
      Catch ex As Exception
        ReportError(ex)
      Finally
        CloseDB(SqlCnn)
      End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: so here's what I did before that
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection(cs)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT picturefile FROM pictures WHERE ID=2;", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

        Dim picture As Image = Nothing

        'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
        Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
            'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.
            picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
        End Using

        answerp.Image = picture

Comment: You've made an assumption that the OP is using ASP.NET but that may not be the case and it is complicating things a little.